# Load values from database when GWT default container starts

Tags: gwt

I am migrating my project to GWT. I load some values from database when the server starts. I want to achieve that with GWT (when I run my application in Eclipse - Run as web application). This is how I am doing currently with Tomcat server.

```
public class StartupListner implements ServletContextListener{

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }

   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try {
          Cache.ruleMap = DatabaseHelper.getConfiguredRules();
          Cache.customerRules = DatabaseHelper.getCustomerRules();
      }catch (Exception e){

     }  
 }
```

Comment: I want to achieve that with GWT (when I run my application in Eclipse - Run as web application). How can I load values from  database when the server starts?

Comment: @gagan Find the answer in your question itself.

Comment: @Braj I think I am confused now :) Do I have to install my application on Tomcat to load values when server starts.

Comment: @gagan you know that how to load some values from database when the server starts in non-GWT project. Am I right? If yes then do it in the same way for GWT project as well.

Comment: @Braj.. My bad.. I forgot to put the listened in web.xml.

Comment: @gagan oh silly mistake. I thought about it but as you told me that you have done it already for non GWT project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you forget to put the listener in web.xml?

GWT applications are the same as any java web application: it relies on the servlet technology. On the server side, nothing changes : the environment is the same

Comment: I forgot that.. Thanks @Zied

Comment: You're welcome gagan, thanks for the vote (many people don't do it) :)

Answer (score 0):

GWT documentation is a good place to start:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html